# Which type conversion to use for mixed types (json and large data object)

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I want to broker mixed content messages between a frontend web application and a data processing pipeline.

In particular, I need to send a data triple comprising:

- metadata: some few bytes to some kB json string
- configuration: also just a few bytes (or empty) to few kB json string
- data: a pretty large data object, somewhere between 1MB to 100MB

I was checking the Spring XD documentation at [1] about possible input / output conversions. However, I want avoid encoding such large data to a json. But then I do not see another option than splitting my message triple into two messages, once as application/json for the two json strings and then binary for the large data piece.

Which type conversion should I use for this mixed content message?

[1] http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#type-conversion

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may want to consider is using a [header enricher](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules/tree/master/header-enricher) to carry the JSON content in the message headers and the data in the payload. I don't know if this addresses your type conversion needs. At which point do you need to bind the JSON to a POJO?

Comment: I don't need to neccessarily. The two json objects and the data will land as files on the node, where local tools process this data (Python and C++ based programs).

Comment: I wonder if I could use Reactor instead, and implement a custom data handler. What do you think?